# Left Outer Join for 2 dataTables with matching column c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datatable, left-join

Help Me Stack Overflow you're my only hope.... Forgive me for being a total newbie, but after hours and hours of research I still have no idea how to make this join happen. What I desperately am trying to achieve is to have a output where all of dataTable1 is intact and the QTY field is added from dataTable2. Unfortunately not all the data has a QTY, so data relation when I made them different tables on the same dataset didn't work for me. So *I think* Left Outer join is the way to go? Any ideas Anyone? Thank you so much for all your time!!!! :)

```
    private void btnReadAccess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet dsResults = new DataSet("dsResults");
        dsResults.Tables.Add("Store");
        dsResults.Tables.Add("Warehouse");

        OleDbConnection conAccess = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\\recent_copy.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;");
        string[] strArrays = this.datePickerFrom.Text.Split(new char[] { '/' });
        string[] strArrays1 = this.datePickerTo.Text.Split(new char[] { '/' });
        string[] text = new string[] { "SELECT Barcode as [Barcode_Store],[description],cat1 ,cat2,discount as [Discount],cost_inc as [Price $],DocketLine.quantity as Sold, (rrp * DocketLine.quantity - discount ) as [Rev $], DocketLine.sales_tax as Goods_Tax FROM Docket,DocketLine,Stock WHERE Docket.docket_date >= #", strArrays[1], "/", strArrays[0], "/", strArrays[2], " ", this.timePickerFrom.Text, "# AND Docket.docket_date <= #", strArrays1[1], "/", strArrays1[0], "/", strArrays1[2], " ", this.timePickerTo.Text, "#  and DocketLine.docket_id = Docket.docket_id  and  DocketLine.stock_id= Stock.stock_id" };
        string str = string.Concat(text);
        OleDbDataAdapter daAccess = new OleDbDataAdapter(new OleDbCommand(str, conAccess));
        DataTable dataTable1 = new DataTable();
        daAccess.Fill(dataTable1);


        OleDbConnection conWarehouse = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\PICKING.PROGRAM\\recent_copy_warehouse.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;");
        string[] qtyselector = { "SELECT Barcode as [Barcode_Warehouse], quantity as [QTY] FROM Stock" };
        string str2 = string.Concat(qtyselector);
        OleDbDataAdapter daWarehouse = new OleDbDataAdapter(new OleDbCommand(str2, conWarehouse));
        DataTable dataTable2 = new DataTable();
        daWarehouse.Fill(dataTable2);

        DataTable dataTableResults = new DataTable();

        dgvResults.DataSource = dataTableResults;
    }
```

Thanks again so much :)

Comment: you can use one  query  to find matching datas know ,why using 2 ?

Comment: post the expected output also

Comment: Thanks utility, would 1 query work even though data is from 2 different databases?

Comment: Hey utility can't get it to work with one query, any other ideas my friend?